# IS it POSSIBLE TO int instead of List

Tags: java, hibernate

I want number of records of a particular table, but my query is returning list i want integer as result
my code is here

```
public int<BorrowerEvaluationDTO> findEvaluations(final String sector, final String investorId) {
    return (List<BorrowerEvaluationDTO>) getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(
            new HibernateCallback() {
                public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException,
                        SQLException {
                    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BorrowerEvaluationDTO.class);
                    criteria.add(Expression.eq("hasEvaluation", true));
                    //      criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("stateOrProvinceId")));
                    //      criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("partnerOrganisation")));
                    if (sector != null && !sector.trim().equals("")) {
                        criteria.add(Expression.eq("sector", sector));
                    }
                    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
                    if (investorId != null && !investorId.trim().equals("")) {


                    }




                    return criteria.list().size();
                }

                ;
            });
}
```

Comment: You've declared the method to return a `List`; change it to return `int` or `char` or whatever.

Comment: return criteria.list(); --this will definitely return a list

Comment: What integer do you actually want? If it's the count, why are you adding an ordering?

Comment: i want number of rows

Comment: no its is not working we cant return int i think, its is giving integer list

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the wrong return type.
Just try to change your function to return an `int` and the return value to `criteria.list().size();`

***EDIT***

You can write your own function. Just make `criteria` global.
For Example:

```
public int getListSize()
{
    return criteria.list().size();
}
```

Comment: its giving list of integer, not int

Comment: i am not able to change the return type to int

Comment: serious?! a LIST OF INT?? From the Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()

Comment: criteria.list().size(); returns list of integer not int

Comment: is your problem solved now? then please mark the answer as right answer.